# Issues with variables UPN in Azure Active Directory

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I Have a csv with multiple user which I want to change their City and their mobile phone number (I am just a guy trying to get better at PowerShell and am an absolute beginner so any help apricated) I have imported the CSV file which has headers and am running a for each object loop through my code but when I run the code I get User not found.  user: error I have removed the part of my code but I have already imported the MSOnline module and I am running the script as a global admin on the tenant so it not an error with permissioning.

Code:

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path "D:\J-O PC\Documents\test.csv" -Delimiter ","
$userid = Out-String -InputObject $csv.userID
$city = Out-String -InputObject $csv.city
$Phone = Out-String -InputObject $csv.phone
ForEach-Object{
    Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $userid -City $city -MobilePhone $Phone
}
```

Error:

```
Set-MsolUser : User Not Found.  User: .
At D:\J-O PC\Documents\James-Oliver\Cloud\test.ps1:11 char:1
+ Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName "$userid" -City "$city" -MobilePhone  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Set-MsolUser], MicrosoftOnlineException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.UserNotFoundException,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.SetUser
```

I have imported the CSV file and running a for each object loop through my code I just need to to go through each user principle name(UPN) in the CSV and change the mobile and city in the same line. I have transformed the UPN into a string since it was refusing to accept the variable when running it as an object any advise and help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ForEach-Object` is not doing anything, you're supposed to pipe the output from `Import-Csv` to it so it actually enumerates the objects. Also, all calls to `Out-String` are completely unneeded.

```bash
Import-Csv -Path 'D:\J-O PC\Documents\test.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    $setMsolUserSplat = @{
        UserPrincipalName = $_.userID
        City              = $_.city
        MobilePhone       = $_.phone
    }

    Set-MsolUser @setMsolUserSplat
}
```

As aside, consider migrating your code to the [Microsoft.Graph Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/installation?view=graph-powershell-1.0), the MSOnline Module is deprecated and the API it's calling behind the scenes will no longer work in the future. See [**Important: Azure AD Graph Retirement and Powershell Module Deprecation**](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-entra-azure-ad-blog/important-azure-ad-graph-retirement-and-powershell-module/ba-p/3848270) for more information.

You can use [`Update-MgUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.users/update-mguser?view=graph-powershell-1.0) as a replacement in this case, the code would look awfully similar:

```
Import-Csv -Path 'D:\J-O PC\Documents\test.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    $updateMgUserSplat = @{
        UserId      = $_.userID
        City        = $_.city
        MobilePhone = $_.phone
    }

    Update-MgUser @updateMgUserSplat
}
```

Comment: Thanks So much this helped me with some other issues I was having with an AD script I was running as well. Also thanks for the heads up about the graph modules I will have to read through and learn the syntax for those too.

Comment: I'm glad this was helpful @James-OliverGouldbourne - luckily in this case the code using the Graph module is very similar - see my update ;)